# How can I cross-compile standard libraries?

Tags: gcc, cross-compilation

I'm trying to set up a cross-compiler for ARM. I followed [this tutorial](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) and I'm at the point now where I can run the cross compiler and get:

```
arm-unknown-eabi-gcc (GCC) 4.8.4 Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software
Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying
conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

But when I try to ./configure Dropbear (the software I'm trying to compile) I get an error:

```
checking for gcc... /home/josh/opt/cross/bin/arm-unknown-eabi-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/josh/src/dropbear-2016.74':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I believe this is because I don't yet have a standard library for the target system, because the tutorial I was following mentions:

> Note how this compiler is not able to compile normal C programs. The
>   cross-compiler will spit errors whenever you want to #include any of
>   the standard headers (except for a select few that actually are
>   platform-independent, and generated by the compiler itself). This is
>   quite correct - you don't have a standard library for the target
>   system yet!

How can I obtain/build a standard library for my target?

Comment: A common standard library on embedded systems is [uClibc](https://www.uclibc.org/).

Comment: You could follow the [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/) build.  It constructs a gcc and glibc that are detached from the libraries it were compiled with.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving this by deleting all my manually built cross compiler stuff and just doing `sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi`, which seems to work out of the box.